# How to use css for an Icon so that it will be responsive for with every text and for every browser resolution as well

Tags: html, css, icons, responsive, nav

I am using nav with li, ul to form a menu bar. In that menu bar I have different-different heading and one arrow icon with them. But the problem is icon is not responsive and it is showing in different-2 position in different -2 screen resolution.

HTML

```
<li>
   <a style="cursor: pointer">
     <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    Agent Access
     <span class="fa fa-chevron-down" id="arrow"></span>
     <ul>
     </ul>
   </a> 
</li>

<li>
    <a style="cursor: pointer">
       <i class="fa fa-file"></i> 
       Reports 
       <span class="fa fa-chevron-down" id="arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul>
    </ul>                           
</li>
```

I wants that arrow icon should be responsive for every menu heading(should be on same place at every li no maater the text is short or long) and on every screen resolution.[See the Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZCO5.png)

Comment: add your CSS with a working example like jsfiddle

Comment: try this: `li a { display: block; width:100%; }`

Comment: Can you post the CSS you're using? **Side note:** _avoid using the same `id` value on multiple elements in your markup. The `id` attribute is meant to be unique to each element. The way you're using `"arrow"`, it could as easily be a class name; and it will give you fewer headaches later on_.

Comment: @Vishnu I used ur css code but , now each arrow is showing below the text on left side what to do?

Comment: I didn't use any specific css code for this icon.